# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :link_id=>"4"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this error ;

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :link_id=>"4"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

The error comes from my `_comment.html.erb` file ;

```rb
<%= comment.content %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', link_comment_path(comment.link, comment) , method: :delete, 
                      data: { confirm: "Are you sure ?"} %>
```

This is my `comments_controller.rb` file;

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
        @comment = @link.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment.link_id = @link.id
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        if @comment.save
         redirect_to link_path(@link)
        else
         render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
        @comment = Comment.find[params[:id]]
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to link_path(@link)
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

This is my `routes.rb` file ;

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :links do
    resources :comments
  end
  root "links#index"
end
```

This is my routes from `rails routes` command ;

```
link_comments     GET    /links/:link_id/comments(.:format)             comments#index                                          
                  POST   /links/:link_id/comments(.:format)             comments#index
new_link_comment  GET    /links/:link_id/comments/new(.:format)         comments#new                                                
edit_link_comment GET    /links/:link_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit                                         
link_comment      GET    /links/:link_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#show                                   
                  PATCH  /links/:link_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update                                       
                  PUT    /links/:link_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update                                        
                  DELETE /links/:link_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#destroy
```

My idea is that I want to make a hacker news clone. Every link page has a comment associates with the link. Right now, I having a problem implementing the delete function for comment.

Comment: quick question, does the error come up when the page is supposed to be presented, or when the "Delete" link is clicked?

Comment: the error comes up when the page is supposed to be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "comment" in the link was a copy/paste error, and you meant @comment:

```
<%= comment.content %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', link_comment_path(@comment.link, @comment),
                      method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure ?"} %>
```

However, I'd be tempted to put your comment destroy on it's own.

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :links, shallow: true do
    resources :comments
  end
  root "links#index"
end
```

**controller**

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find[params[:id]]
  @link = Comment.link
  @comment.destroy

  redirect_to link_path(@link)
end
```

**view** (I hate ERB, have some nice HAML)

```
= comment.content
= link_to 'Delete', @comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure ?"}
```

Comment: can you explain the controller part. Btw, it's work

Comment: rather than passing in the link as it's own id, it can be found from the comment directly (as you did in the view).  you just need to record the "link" from the "comment" before you destroy the "comment". the "shallow: true" in routes is in some ways the clever bit, as you can see from your new routes.  it creates the destroy directly, even is the index/show/new are all off of the "link" object